# Create a bash shell script that can create a PHP program

Tags: php, bash, sh, tee

Looking for the ability to automate the ability for a bash script to take the contents of a .PHP program and create it in a specific directory with permissions of 755. I basically want to give the user this one .sh script that will install the appropriate programs and files to get a website up and running. The problem I'm running into is the PHP variables won't save in the output file. I'm using the following command:

```
echo "<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
require_once '/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/account.php';
require_once '/var/www/osbs/zang/library/Zang.php';
$To = $_POST['subject'];
$Body = $_POST['text'];
# If you want the response decoded into an Array instead of an Object, set 
response_to_array to TRUE, otherwise, leave it as-is
$response_to_array = false;
# Now what we need to do is instantiate the library and set the required 
options defined above
$zang = Zang::getInstance();
# This is the best approach to setting multiple options recursively Take note that you cannot set non-existing options
$zang -> setOptions(array(
'account_sid' => $account_sid,
'auth_token' => $auth_token,
'response_to_array' => $response_to_array ));
?>" | tee /var/www/output.php
```

The output.php file is missing all the variables that start with $ can you guys help?

Comment: surely you don't literally want to hard-code some PHP code into your bash script? Shouldn't it be just copying files around, and maybe creating a database?

Comment: you need to escape the `$` in your bash script with backslash `\$`

Comment: or use single quotes around your php code in the bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle the quoting issues here is to use a ["here-doc"](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

```
cat >/var/www/output.php <<"EOF"
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
require_once '/var/www/osbs/PHPAPI/account.php';
require_once '/var/www/osbs/zang/library/Zang.php';
$To = $_POST['subject'];
$Body = $_POST['text'];
# If you want the response decoded into an Array instead of an Object,
# set response_to_array to TRUE, otherwise, leave it as-is
$response_to_array = false;
# Now what we need to do is instantiate the library and set the
# required options defined above
$zang = Zang::getInstance();
# This is the best approach to setting multiple options recursively.
# Take note that you cannot set non-existing options
$zang -> setOptions(array(
'account_sid' => $account_sid,
'auth_token' => $auth_token,
'response_to_array' => $response_to_array ));
?>
EOF
```

There is no need for `tee` (unless you really want to dump all that stuff to the console, which seems unnecessary). Quoting the delimiter string (`<<"EOF"`) effectively quotes the entire here-doc, preventing the expansion of variables.